# How to update phusion passenger + nginx on ubuntu server?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04, passenger

I have a remote server with Ubuntu 12.04 on board, how could I upgrade Phusion Passenger Nginx edition? Should I recompile nginx?

**UPDATE**

I just ran `gem update passenger` and then changed version of passenger in nginx conf file.
After that I've got:

```
nginx: [alert] Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because its executable (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.38/buildout/agents/PassengerWatchdog) does not exist. This probably means that your Phusion Passenger installation is broken or incomplete, or that your 'passenger_root' directive is set to the wrong value. Please reinstall Phusion Passenger or fix your 'passenger_root' directive, whichever is applicable. (-1: Unknown error)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to re-run passenger-install-nginx-module. See the upgrade instructions at the official manual: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#rubygems_generic_install

Answer (score 4):

Recently I upgrade ruby from version 2.1.3 to 2.1.5 and got the same issue. I'm fix it with 2 step follow:

Step 1: Reinstall nginx module

- If you using rbenv

  passenger-install-nginx-module
- Using rvm

  rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module

Step 2: Restart nginx

```
sudo service nginx restart
```